# Return string not matching textbox text

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have bit of code in my program that will not let and operator start another batch until they finish the one that they are on but still allows another operator to start the same batch. The sqldatareader is returning the correct data i.e. 17080387-002 but the program keeps going to the "Please finish batch" step. I'm trying to figure out if it possibly has anything to do with how the batch is being returned.

```
public void BatchLockOut()
    {
        string eventID = null;
        string batchLock = null;
        string enteredLot = TextBoxLot.Text;
        string connectionString = "";
        string commandText = "SELECT BadgeNo, Container_ID, Event_ID, Event_Time " +
                               "FROM dbo.Custom_EventLog " +
                               "WHERE Event_Time IN (SELECT MAX(Event_Time) FROM dbo.Custom_EventLog WHERE BadgeNo = @BADGENO)";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@BADGENO", SqlDbType.NChar, 10).Value = TextBoxLogin.Text;
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    eventID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Event_ID"]).ToString();
                    batchLock = reader["Container_ID"] as string;
                    break;
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        if (batchLock == null)
        {
            ButtonBeginStir.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else if (batchLock != enteredLot)
        {
            if (eventID == "1")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please finish previous stir", "Finish Stir", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                ClearForm();
            }
            else
            {
                ButtonBeginStir.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
        else if (batchLock == enteredLot)
        {
            if (eventID == "1")
            {
                ButtonEndStir.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else if (eventID == "2")
            {
                ButtonBeginStir.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do a console.writeline on the value of enteredLot and batchLock  please, and show the results?

Comment: @Trey could you explain where and how to use console.writeline? I haven't used it before.

Comment: Or just run in debug mode and put a breakpoint there.

Comment: batchLock is "17080387-002       (Lot of space)         " and enteredLot is "17080387-002".

Comment: I don't believe your query is logically correct. For it to be logically correct, Event_Time must be unique in the table because of the way you structured your query. Plus, the datareader while loop assumes a single row. So perhaps a better query is:
SELECT top 1 BadgeNo, Container_ID, Event_ID, Event_Time 
FROM dbo.Custom_EventLog WHERE BadgeNo = @BADGENO
ORDER BY Event_Time DESC
That may or may not help this particular problem.

Comment: if batchLock has lots of space and enteredLot does not, wouldn't that mean they are not equal ==? Or does C# trim the spaces for you behind the scenes (I don't know to be honest).

Comment: ahhhh ok on your compare(yes I understand this is not culture aware) do a .ToUpper().Trim() on both values then try

Comment: @Trey yes exactly, trim those results and it should work.

Comment: Thanks all, that definitely worked!